# How do you merge numeric columns?

Tags: r

My Data looks like this:

```
      x  y  z
    1 na na 4
    2 na na 5
    3 na 4  na
    4 na 2  na
    5 7  na na
    6 9  na na
```

I tried paste and merge, but then the output looks like this:

```
      x
    1 na na 4
    2 na na 4
    3 na  4 na
```

I want numbers only and I want them in only one column. This is what I want:

```
      x 
    1 4
    2 5
    3 4
    4 2
    5 7
    6 9
```

Do you guys know how to do that? You would be a great help to me! Thank you!

Comment: @akrun [You can instantly reopen any question closed as a duplicate that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/220122). [if you have a gold tag-badge for a tag associated with a question that's been closed as a duplicate, you can edit the duplicate links to replace, add, remove or re-arrange them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/220122).

Comment: @anjama that post has several answers that use either `dplyr::coalesce` or other implementations of the same type of function. The answers become complicated because part of the question was about measuring efficiency, but the solutions themselves should cover it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1  %>%
   transmute(x = coalesce(x, y, z))
```

assuming that `na`s are real `NA`s (missing values) and not character strings

Comment: It worked, but it's not numeric anymore. And the as.numeric code shows me this error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. How do I change that?

Comment: @MalaDhyan  Could be that your columns were not numeric to start with.  I would use `df1 %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) %>% transmute(x = coalesce(x, y, z))`